# Nested while loop inside for loop only iterate over first element

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, while-loop

My snippet below written on **R** to remove every element in the `vector` which is a multiple of x `for each` x in the `vector`.

When the function runs, the loop only works for the first element in the vector, ie, 2, and it doesn't verify the remaining elements such as 3,4,5,6. How can I fix it?

```
my_function <- function(n){
X <- 2:n
i <- 2
 for (x in X){
   while (x*i <= n){
     a <- match(x*i,X)
     X <- X[-(a)]
     i <- i+1
  }
  print(X)
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following :

```
my_function <- function(n){
  #Create a sequence from 2 to n
  X <- 2:n
  #For every value in X
  for(i in X) {
    #Create a sequence from i + i to n with steps of i
    vals = seq(min(i + i, n), n, i)
    #Check which values in X are multiple
    inds <- X %in% vals
    #If any value is present 
    if(any(inds))
      #Remove it from X
      X <- X[!inds]
     }
     #Return remaining X
     return(X)
}

my_function(6)
#[1] 2 3 5
my_function(12)
#[1]  2  3  5  7 11
```

Comment: No, for example for n=6, the result is: 2,3,5

Comment: Why do you include 2, 3, 5 and not 1 and 4?

Comment: Because the multiples of 2 are 4,6; the multiples of 3 are 6; the multiples of 4,5,6 are out of the list. So, I quit 4 and 6 and I remain with 2,3,5. And the vector starts in the number 2, I don't have 1 in my vector.

Comment: For example, for n=12 I have 2,3,5,7,11

Comment: I have updated the answer to do that. By the way, it is not clear from your question what you want to do. Perhaps, you could include this example in the question so that it is clear.